# Room SQL query to retrieve entity key and sum of values

Tags: android, mysql, sql, android-room

My database contains a list of these "Movement" class:

```
@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
private int NumeroDeOperacion;
private int FechaYear;
private int FechaMonth;
private int FechaDay;
private String TipoOperacion;
private String Category;
private String Notas;
private float Quantity;
```

In one of my queries I'd like to retrieve only `Category` and `Quantity` so I created another POJO object like this:

```
public class Category {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Category")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Quantity")
    public float quantity;

    public Category(){}

}
```

What I'm triying to get is all the different `Category` in a specific year and the SUM of all `Quantity`.

So, let's say I have something like this:

```
Category   Quantity

A          5
B          10
C          5
A          15
B          20
```

I'd like to get:

```
Category   Quantity

A          20
B          30
C          5
```

I tried with this query but it is only getting the last entry of each `Category`:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT Category, Quantity FROM OperacionesTable WHERE FechaYear = :year GROUP BY CategoryORDER BY Quantity DESC")
LiveData<List<Category>> getGastosCategoryTotalsInYear(int year);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum the quantities, you have to use `SUM`.

Also, there is no need for `DISTINCT`, since `GROUP BY` already takes care of that. My guess is that you added distinct, because there was an error. The error was there, because Quantity was neither in the group by columns, nor used in an aggregate function. This is typically an error (except in MySQL, which will just give you a random result).

Anyway, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  Category, 
  SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity -- Column alias, to give the column a proper name
FROM 
  OperacionesTable 
WHERE 
  FechaYear = :year 
GROUP BY 
  Category
ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC
```

Comment: Working like a charm. Thanks a lot. I wish I knew some more about SQL...

Comment: A bit of practice..  And you weren't that far off anyway. :-)